# Redireccionar Index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Estaba usando este código para redireccionar las URLs que llevan index.php a las que no llevan index.php, y asi quitarlo de en medio.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index\.php/[^\ ]+
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Me funciona para las URLs de las categorías principales, pero no para las subcategorías que tiene la sección entrevistas como por ejemplo esta

`http://www.eexcellence.es/index.php/entrevistas/management-espanol`

Comment: RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)?$ /$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: Thanks for the code, is not working but I guess it has to be with the rest of the code I have on the htaccess. La página no está redirigiendo adecuadamente

Firefox ha detectado que el servidor está redirigiendo la solicitud a esta dirección de una manera en la que nunca terminará.

Este problema a veces está causado por desactivar o rechazar la recepción de cookies.